# Safari Push запрос на подписку не работает в Safari 10

Tags: javascript, safari, push-уведомления

Добрый день, проблема заключается в том, что не работает запрос запрос на подписку на пуш уведомления в safari 10, в safari 9 все работает и пуши доходят до адресата.
Код стандартный из документации:

```
const websitePushID = 'web.ru.xxx';
const webServiceUrl = 'https://xxx.ru';
var permissionData = {};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    webPush.pushButton = $('.js-push-btn') || false;
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(webPush.initialiseState);
    } else {
        if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
            permissionData = window.safari.pushNotification.permission(websitePushID);
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-push-btn').on('click', function () {
        checkRemotePermission(permissionData);
    });
});

var checkRemotePermission = function (permissionData) {
    if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
        try {
            console.log('default');
            window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
                webServiceUrl,
                websitePushID,
                {},
                checkRemotePermission
            );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
        console.log('denied');
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('granted');
    }
};
```

После нажатия на кнопку в консоль выводится 'default', затем 'denied'. То есть колбек функции срабатывает, но видимо с ошибкой. xxx/v1/log по идее записыват логи

```
file_put_contents ('./files/logs.txt', json_encode ($_REQUEST));
```

Однако в файле logs.txt пустой массив [].
Если бы был неверный pushPackage, то все это дело не работало бы в Safari 9, но т.к. работает - ума не приложу в чем дело.